# Happy Number String Python function

Tags: python, math

I am pretty new to Python and just got started in Leet and I am doing the Happy Number question, only half of the test cases have been passed. I would appreciate any help. Thanks

A happy number is a number defined by the following process: Starting with any positive integer, replace the number by the sum of the squares of its digits, and repeat the process until the number equals 1 (where it will stay), or it loops endlessly in a cycle which does not include 1. Those numbers for which this process ends in 1 are happy numbers.

My test cases were 19, 100 where it output True correctly but when I do 7, it is wrong

```
    def isHappy(self, n: int) -> bool:
        if (n == 1):
            return True
        sum = 0
        flag = False
        for j in range(1,100):  
            x = str(n)
            a = list(x)
            for i in range(0,len(a)):
              sum += int(a[i])*int(a[i])
              if sum == 1:
                return True
                break
            else:
                    x = sum 
                    return False
```

Comment: There is no reason why anyone else should know what this "happy number" question is, what the test cases are, or what kind of help you need.

Comment: I don't see anything in the instructions about looping from 1 to 100.

Comment: Please fix indentation, and remove variables that have no function (self, x,  flag).

Comment: @khelwood I think looping 100 times counts as “endless” cycle

Comment: In the `else` branch, you assign the sum to `x`, but at the beginning of the next iteration, you re-assign `x` from `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation using a set to keep track of numbers that we have already seen.  (I've removed the `self` argument here for sake of something that can be run outside of your test class.)

```
def isHappy(n: int) -> bool:
    seen = set()
    while True:
        if n == 1:
            return True
        if n in seen:
            return False
        seen.add(n)
        n = sum(int(c) ** 2 for c in str(n))
```

Your code has various issues aside from the fact that the number 100 is arbitrary.

Mainly that you never update `n` in your loop. Also you do not wait for the completion of the `for` loop before testing `sum` (in fact your `break` is never reached), you initialise `sum` only once, and you return `False` prematurely. Here is a minimally corrected version of your code, although still subject to the fact that there is no rule about 100 maximum iterations.

```
def isHappy(n: int) -> bool:
    if (n == 1):
        return True
    for j in range(1,100):
        x = str(n)
        a = list(x)
        sum = 0
        for i in range(0,len(a)):
          sum += int(a[i])*int(a[i])
        if sum == 1:
            return True
        else:
            n = sum 
    return False
```

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot. I am still getting used to the indentation in Python hence my errors in the loops and conditions.  Also, what is the O(n) for my code and yours, I am unsure but certainly mine is slower as I am not memoizing the values

Comment: @RahmanFahd Hard to describe it in terms of an O(n) or whatever in this case, but the purpose of a set is really that without keeping track of what numbers you have already visited, it is hard to know exactly when to stop, you just need to keep iterating for a large number of iterations (your 100) and hope that that number was large enough to cover all cases within the range of input values that you might want to use it for.